# What is a marginal fermi liquid in a nutshell?

Tags: condensed-matter, fermi-liquids

I would like to know what are the main differences between the normal Fermi liquid theory and a marginal fermi liquid theory. What kind of systems can be described by the marginal liquid theory? What are the consequences of considering an electron gas as a marginal fermi liquid?

Comment: Paper in which marginal Fermi liquid is proposed: Phys. Rev. Lett. 63, 1996 (1989).